# Program refuses to install in Wine, telling me that “run this installer as a normal user instead of run as admin”

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm trying to install a program that is only available to windows/mac that I use for my work (there is no alternative software for this one).

I don't run wine as sudo and I'm using Kubuntu 19.04.

I don't want to run a partition or virtual machine when attempting to install it I get the following message.

```
Installation has failed

Please re-run this installer as a normal user instead of "Run as Administrator".
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't told us your what flavor or release you are running, and it looks like you've tried to install with elevated (sudo) privileges; have you?

Comment: you may want to try running it in Playonlinux see if it will install.  Not all windows programs will run under wine either. But with playonlinux you can try different wine versions some programs run better under older or newer versions.  good luck.

Comment: No. I don't run wine using Sudo. I will give playonlinux a try. Im using kubuntu 19.04

Comment: Play on linux do not solve this.

Comment: Every figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Install and use `winehq-staging` to use Windows UAC.

Source:

- https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30206